# Print all positional arguments in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line

I'm trying to write a PowerShell function that prints out all its arguments.

**ArgChecker.ps1**

```
function Print-Args
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param ([string[]]$words)
    Write-Verbose "Count: $($words.Count)"
    Write-Output "Passed arguments:"
    $words
}
```

I'd also like to call it from a command prompt.

I'm doing it like this

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "& { . .\ArgChecker.ps1; Print-Args 'hi' 'Two' -Verbose }"
```

but it is throwing an error `Print-Args : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Two'`.

Is there any way to write the function so that it can accept an unlimited amount of parameters in that format? I think I'm looking for something similar to the `params` keyword from C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular functions, you can use the [$args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#args) automatic variable.

```
function Write-Args {
    $args
}
```

If you need a cmdlet with `CmdletBinding`, you can use the [ValueFromRemainingArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#valuefromremainingarguments-argument) option:

```
function Write-Args {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]]$Arguments
    )
    $Arguments
}
```

Note however, because of the `CmdletBinding`, `-Verbose` will not appear in that list, because it's a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1). If you want to list those too, you could use the [$PSBoundParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#psboundparameters) automatic variable.